# Kentico 8.2 deploying web parts

Tags: import, kentico

I need to push changes made in **CMS -> Pages -> Design** tab (web parts) from our dev server to a production server.  Is there a way to import these changes to the production site without affecting anything else in the db? E.g. nothing in the Form tab should be updated.

Comment: So you've made changes to the page template, and you want to sync those changes?  If you have your staging module setup properly, then you should see an entry that has the name of the page template that you changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content staging is the best way to do this.

If you have not setup content staging yet, [here](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Configuring+content+staging) are details how to do so. After you enable Staging module you may need to do to that page once again to that page Design tab, open settings for any of the web parts and save it without any changes, so staging module will notice changes and log sync task.

If staging was already enabled, you need to go to Staging application -> Objects tab -> Web Site -> Development -> Page Templates. This will give you all page templates, those were changed. Select the one you need and sync it. If your template is not available there try to locate it under Global Objects.

Comment: Thank you.  If I understand correctly, it will only sync changes made after logging was enabled?  The changes on both our end and the client site were made before logging was enabled.

Comment: @D3v It does not sync anything by default, but logs sync task, that you can run if you want to. If you have staging enabled now, just go and save the template once again, so system will log sync task, that you will be able to run.

Comment: Technically, Content Staging will sync content by default.  There is a scheduled task which is enabled by default.  So if Content Staging is enabled and the scheduled task is enabled, the content related changes which are staged, will be synchronized.

Comment: @BrendenKehren according to documentation (https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Automatic+content+synchronization), you have to enable scheduled task in order to sync changes automatically.

Comment: You're correct Roman with the documentation, problem is the 6 different installs of v9 I've done in the last few months, this was enabled already by default.  Every install of version 8.x was enabled by default too.  So the documentation is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

[See the answer posted over on the Kentico DevNet](http://devnet.kentico.com/questions/kentico-8-2-deploying-web-parts).

"*If your license allows it, use Content Staging as Zachary mentions. If not, use import and export of that page template.*

*For reference, anything on the Page, Form and Properties tabs, are content related changes and will not affect any objects like templates, layouts and webpart properties. Changes on the Design tab are changes to page templates, layouts and webpart properties themselves, which are objects and do not affect content changes UNLESS you remove a webpart which was displaying or has content inside it.*"